# How to design layout with different shapes using XML?

Tags: android, xml-drawable

I want to design a layout.It includes different shapes and that should be attach each other.
[image]

How to do it in xml?. Please any one suggest me.

Comment: ... in **xml**?? Possibly by using a `VectorDrawable` (API Lebel 21+). But I'd rather use a separate SVG for each **Tangram** piece.

Comment: am new to android.How to do it in canvas drawing.Through java code?

Comment: Yes, but I just edited my comment. Please, read it again.

Comment: can you suggest me some links ?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/